# How long does it take to build a Falcon 9 Rocket?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, construction

This came up while discussing the recent Falcon 9 failure with a friend.  She posed the question:

> How long does it take SpaceX to construct a new Falcon 9?

For the sake of the question, presume:

- No new engineering designs/equipment to be developed
- No new launch facilities
- Time from request for creation to ready to launch

If possible, please also give clarification on time subtracted for Salvaged/Backstocked parts (ie: recovered stages, engines made en mass previously, etc) and how long those parts would take to construct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publicly SpaceX officials have verbally said that they are aiming to build at a rate of 40 cores (First Stages) a year.  As of just before the CRS-7 mission they said they were at a 20/year rate.

52/40= 1.3 weeks/core for their desired optimum rate.
52/20= 2.6 weeks/core for their current state.

They were aiming for 12-13 launches (one being a Falcon Heavy, so two more cores) thus 14-15 cores to be used in 2015. This will not likely happen due the CRS-7 loss of mission.

They build the upper stage at a somewhat slower rate, since their stated desire is a mix of 10 Falcon 9 and 10 Falcon Heavy boosters a year to get to 40 cores, which only requires 20 upper stages.

Comment: Why build 40 reusable cores per year? Would they load them with sand from the Boca Chica Beach, or what?

Comment: That is an interesting different question.  If they seriously believe they need to hit 40 cores per year, are they doubting reuse?  If they can reuse them, at 40 core/year that is a crap load of flights they are planning for at 10 flights/core.  400 core flights/year?  THAT is extreme.

Comment: Please note that you are answering a different question than the one the OP asked. Production rate != time from keel to christening

Comment: @DeerHunter An interesting point. The more I think about it, the less I see the distinction.

Comment: @geoffc - how many production lines/streams are there at SpaceX? That's the key item to convert your numbers into those requested by the OP.

Comment: @geoffc Thanks for the information!  Can you provide a link to where they verbally discussed their production aims?  I'd love to watch a video if there is one.  Also as DeerHunter further said, is there any information regarding how many can be in construction simultaneously?

Comment: I'm sure you can find more recent pics than these shots from 2 years ago: http://www.spacex.com/news/2013/09/24/production-spacex - 4 abreast, it seems. One should also measure the Hawthorne, CA facility as a cross-check.